# Recyclerview list end overlay color and alpha

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

How can I change the grey or white overlay that comes on recyclerview when we try to scroll even when we reached the end(top or bottom) of list. I am not able to find the property name to which I can use to do it.

Comment: I think that is a default property in the scroll.If you want you can make it using style sheets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RecyclerView` take the shadow from the `colorPrimary` of your Theme.

You need to create new theme for `RecyclerView` then apply this Theme to your `RecyclerView`

In below example themes  `colorPrimary` is `colorGreen` so it will take green color shadow.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/ha_citiesRC"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
     android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
```

**theme**

```
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorGreen</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

 </style>
```

Comment: It is shown but its very dull, I need a dark one, just like we get on whatsapp app

Comment: @ManishPatiyal try with [android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:requiresFadingEdge)

Comment: @ManishPatiyal Make sure you run your app on +21 devices .

Answer (score 0):

try this in your RecylerView

```
  android:overScrollMode="never"

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:overScrollMode="never"
android:background="#000"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Actually, I want to change its color or alpha of the overlay, with your code it just hide the overlay

Answer (score 0):

Change the ColorPrimary for that Activity and Fragment using style
Firstly create the style

```
 <style name="RecyclerView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">"Enter the Color Which you want"</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

After then just set the style to Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.RecyclerView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```